# Proof that span which is containing matrices is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How can I proof that the following span is a vector space and that its isomorphic together with the matrix multiplication to the field $\mathbb C$?

$$V = \operatorname{span}_\mathbb{R} \bigg( \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, 
\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}
\right\} \bigg)$$

Comment: By definition *Span* means the smallest vector subspace that contains the given matrices. Your second question is a completely different one and you would need to provide some of your own thoughts. Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that $V$ is refered to be the collection of all the linear combinations that you can form with the matrices
$$
v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}
\textrm{ and }
v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0&-1\\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
So, $V = \{av_1 + bv_2 :\, a,b \in \mathbb R\}$. To prove that $V$ is actually a real vector space you need to prove basically two things: the sum of matrices and the scalar multiplication are well-defined operations in $V$, that is, if you have two matrices $v$ and $w$, in $V$, then $u+v$ is also in $V$, i.e. $u+v$ also can be written as a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Once you prove the above, just check things like associativity, conmutativity, find the zero vector, the inverses, and so on.

Secondly, to prove that $V$ is isomorphic to the real vector space $\mathbb C$, you need to find a bijective function $f:V\to\mathbb C$ that is linear:
$$\forall u,v\in V \ \forall c\in\mathbb R \ : \ f(cu+v) = cf(u)+f(v)$$
and that preserves the multiplication:
$$\forall u,v\in V \ : \ f(uv) = f(u)f(v)$$
I let you check that the function defined as
$$f\begin{pmatrix} a&-b \\ b&a \end{pmatrix} = a+bi$$
satisfies them.